# Why does Android bond even when asked not to bond?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have developed an application on an on-board device which allows a smartphone to be able to connect in secure BLE.

Everything works fine but I notice that every time I do a "pairing" via an Android smartphone, that the smartphone "bonds" the device even though I specified in the request that I did not want bondage. I don't have this problem on IOS.

Here are the requests that are sent by my on-board device to the smartphone:

- [Security request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBIGv.png)
- [Pairing response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Odgo2.png)

Is it possible that Android does not support "pairing only"? If it is paired, it does a "boding" automatically even if it has received a request asking it not to do a bond?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Non-bondable mode" is mandatory to support in the Bluetooth Core specification. If Android makes a permanent bond, even though you say to not bond in the "Pairing response", it's a bug in Android. Please file a bug report to Android Open Source Project (AOSP).